# Using `wait_for` in discord.py Cogs

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating something where the bot will randomly ask a "scramble this sentence" question and the user will have to answer the question. Now when I use `client.wait_for` to wait for the user/s response, the `wait_for` stops the code completely when I tried using breakpoints. Why does this happen? I think I'm struggling on how to use this in a cog. This is my cog code without imports:

```
class firework_economy(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        else:
            rand_num = randint(1, 10)
            print(rand_num)
            if rand_num == 5:
                ss = open('scrambled sentences.txt','r')
                sslist = ss.readlines()
                chosen_sentence = choice(sslist)
                await message.reply(f"Unscramble the following sentence for a chance to win a firework:\n\n`{chosen_sentence}`")
                def check(m):
                     return m.content == 'answer' and m.channel == message.channel
                msg = await commands.Bot().wait_for("message")
                await message.channel.send(f"{msg.author.mention} was first!")

   

async def setup(bot):
  await bot.add_cog(firework_economy(bot))
```

Comment: This is because the code is synchronous. You need to await asychronously using something like this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables

Comment: With "it stops the code" I assume he means that it just crashes/stops running that function instead of "it freezes the main thread". The code here is never gonna work because it raises exceptions for multiple reasons. Highly doubt that this is an async issue.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. I have a lack of proper terms when it comes to coding 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`commands.Bot.wait_for()` doesn't make any sense. You're supposed to call the `wait_for` method on an **instance** of the `Bot` class. It's not a static method.

```py
commands.Bot  # This is the name of a class
bot = commands.Bot(...)  # This is an instance of the commands.Bot class
```

To get access to it in a `Cog`, the most common solution is to pass it in as an argument to the `__init__()` when you create the `Cog` instance.

The examples in the docs also clearly show this (using `client` instead of `discord.Client`): https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for

Next, the arguments to `wait_for` are wrong. You can't pass multiple event types to wait for.

```py
wait_for("event", "message", ...)  # You can't do this
```

"event" isn't even a valid thing to `wait_for`, so that wouldn't work either way. I wouldn't know what "event" would even be triggered by.

Lastly, you made a `check` function but you're passing `check=None` so you're not using it...

Take a close look at the examples in the docs page (linked above).

All of these should be giving you an error message, both in your console and in your IDE, though - so not sure how you got here & you may not have configured `logging` properly.

Comment: I now get the error `TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'command_prefix'` in my `discord.log` file. I have updated the post with my current code

Comment: I think I got the instance correction wrong

Comment: @DRags you're now randomly creating a _new_ instance (without passing arguments) instead of using the existing one in your cog. To refer to an attribute of a class, use `self.<name>`, or in your case `self.bot`.

Comment: Ahh yes I used that before and it didn't work - probably due to one of the other issues. I tried it and everything works perfectly. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You’re on track but there are a few errors.
Here’s a snippet of your code.

```
def check(m):
   return m.content == 'answer' and m.channel == message.channel
msg = await commands.Bot().wait_for("message")
```

Your check function is mostly correct for what you are doing, you just need to replace the `‘answer’` with `answer` and then the variable `answer` would be like `chosen_list`: `answer = ‘find the answer in the txt file’`

For msg you have totally messed it up.
commands.Bot() is wrong and should be bot or client so here bot.
`msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=10)`

‘message’ initialises that the bot is waiting for a message, check is equal to our check function that will run when the bot is waiting for a message and timeout is the length of time the bot will wait before it stops waiting for a message.

[Here is the docs reference on wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for)

Comment: you already know it works